# Error Showing While Typing "npm start" on Gitbash

Tags: git, bash, angular, typescript

I've been learning "Lynda's Learning Angular 2" course. I have been stuck on the third video of the course. I have created "learnangular" folder, install all the dependencies using "npm install" command, view all the branches and check out "02_01b." However, when I type "npm start" on git bash, a lot of errors are being displayed.

How can I fix this issue?

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(39,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(19,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts(21,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/offline_compiler.d.ts(31,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts(13,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(40,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.d.ts(42,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(35,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts(36,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_init.d.ts(16,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(106,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(122,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(148,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(150,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(53,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(61,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(14,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.d.ts(28,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/src/resource_loader/resource_loader_impl.d.ts(10,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(47,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(353,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(354,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(355,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(356,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(357,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(358,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(359,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(360,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(360,97): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(361,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(362,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(363,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(364,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(365,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(365,117): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(366,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(368,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(369,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(370,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(371,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(434,6): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Symbol'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(459,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(467,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(468,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(470,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(471,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(475,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(477,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(693,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(694,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyKey'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(710,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(711,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(826,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PromiseConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(841,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(845,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(845,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterator'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(856,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1479,36): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1483,43): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1487,50): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1491,40): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1495,38): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1499,37): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1503,39): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1507,38): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1511,39): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1515,37): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1519,43): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1523,43): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(1527,43): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2294,36): error TS2339: Property 'for' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2298,43): error TS2339: Property 'hasInstance' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2302,50): error TS2339: Property 'isConcatSpreadable' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2306,40): error TS2339: Property 'iterator' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2310,38): error TS2339: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2314,37): error TS2339: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2318,39): error TS2339: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2322,38): error TS2339: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2326,39): error TS2339: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2330,37): error TS2339: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2334,43): error TS2339: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2338,43): error TS2339: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts(2342,43): error TS2339: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! learn-angular@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-angular@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the learn-angular package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs learn-angular
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls learn-angular
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\John\Desktop\learnangular\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `es6`, try to change `tsconfig.json`.

for example

```
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "target":"es6",
      "module":"commonjs",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "sourceMap":true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
      "experimentalDecorators":true,
      "removeComments":false,
      "noImplicitAny":true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors":true
   },
   "exclude":[
      "node_modules",
      "vendor"
   ]
}
```